# Facebook FQL: I want to get all the posts that a user wrote on friends timelines

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I only want the posts( no likes or comments). Anyone can help with an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in FQL, consider using the regular Graph API and pagination on the following endpoint with `read_stream` permission

`friend_id/feed?fields=message`

Comment: I gave up on that a long time ago. I used a different idea.