# Facebook Graph API Get Comments outside of Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been learning how the Facebook Graph API works for a while and managed to get the info out of the "me" , "me/likes" and "me/posts" edges,

My question is in regard to the "me/posts" edge; it retrieves all the posts on the user's wall only not the posts/comments he made on another page and or a friends wall, all i get is a "type": "status" JSON node with no actual "message": "" node in the JSON entry saying "XYZ commented on a status."

**Example:**

```json
 {
 "id": "<USER_ID>_<POST_ID>",
 "from": {
    "id": "<USER_ID>",
    "name": "XYZ"
 },
 "story": "XYZ commented on a status.",
 "story_tags": {
    "0": [
       {
          "id": "<USER_ID>",
          "name": "XYZ",
          "offset": 0,
          "length": 3,
          "type": "user"
       }
    ]
 },
 "privacy": {
    "value": ""
 },
 "type": "status",
 "created_time": "2014-11-11T22:18:25+0000",
 "updated_time": "2014-11-11T22:18:25+0000"
 }
```

As you can see there is no "message": "value" node included in the JSON returned its just informing me that he made a comment but i need the value or the message of that comment !

Now, failed attempts i have gone through so far includes:
 1. [Requesting <PAGE_ID/FRIEND_ID>/posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179767/facebook-fql-i-want-to-get-all-the-posts-that-a-user-wrote-on-friends-timelines?answertab=oldest#tab-top): I'm unaware of the
    PAGE_ID/FRIEND_ID with the information i have from the previous
    JSON.
 2. [Requesting the <POST_ID> returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212737/facebook-graph-api-get-reference-to-commented-on-posts): As explained it
    doesn't work and for my case a 100% of the time.

So is there an official way to know what the user wrote on fan page or on a comment he made on a friend's public wall through the Facebook Graph API or even the FQL API ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long standing bug in Facebook, probably older than two years.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/648986871793611/ https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/522743067756848/

Facebook doesn't seem interested in fixing this.

There is no official way to do this until Facebook fixes the incomplete data.